# Remove single letters from strings in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a DataFrame where a column is filled with strings. I want to remove any appearance of single letters from the column. So far, I have tried:

```
df['STRI'] = df['STRI'].map(lambda x: " ".join(x.split() if len(x) >1)
```

I wish to input `ABCD X WYZ` and get `ABCD WYZ`.

Comment: Your check is about the whole string. Do it for each word: `df['STRI'].map(lambda x: ' '.join(word for word in x.split() if len(word)>1))` Although probably there are better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
df['STRI'] = npi['STRI'].str.replace(r'\b\w\b', '').str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')
```

---

Eg:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=['X ABCD X X WEB X'], columns=['c1'])
print df, '\n'
df.c1 = df.c1.str.replace(r'\b\w\b', '').str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')
print df
```

Output:

```
                 c1
0  X ABCD X X WEB X 

           c1
0   ABCD WEB
```

Comment: This does not generalize, as the original question asks for removing any single characters.

Comment: Try again. Thanks @piRSQuared.

Comment: Tried again after your edit, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you include `npi.head()` and `df.head()` ?

Comment: @piRSquared This will not take care of edge cases.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that I didn't import re. It worked once I did. (Or at least I am hoping that it is in my huge dataset).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `str.replace` and regex.  The pattern `\b\w\b` will replace any single word character with a word boundary.  See working example below:

Example using series:

```
s = pd.Series(['Katherine','Katherine and Bob','Katherine I','Katherine', 'Robert', 'Anne', 'Fred', 'Susan', 'other'])

   s.str.replace(r'\b\w\b','').str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')

0            Katherine
1    Katherine and Bob
2            Katherine
3            Katherine
4               Robert
5                 Anne
6                 Fred
7                Susan
8                other
dtype: object
```

Another example with your test data:

```
    s = pd.Series(['ABCD','X','WYZ'])

0    ABCD
1       X
2     WYZ
dtype: object

s.str.replace(r'\b\w\b','').str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')

0    ABCD
1        
2     WYZ
dtype: object
```

With your data it is:

```
df['STRI'].str.replace(r'\b\w\b','').str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')
```

Comment: `.strip()` will replace only front and end spaces. In between spaces will be left out.

Answer (score 3):

***list comprehension***

```
[
    ' '.join([i for i in s.split() if len(i) > 1])
    for s in npi.STRI.values.tolist()
]
```

***`str.split`***

```
s = npi.STRI.str.split(expand=True).stack()
s[s.str.len() > 1].groupby(level=0).apply(' '.join)
```

Comment: `.str.replace().str.replace()` will be efficient?

Comment: @MYGz use an apply and embed both replaces in the same apply